# Why won't music play using SDL

Tags: c++, sdl

```
#include<iostream>
#include <SDL_mixer.h>
#include <SDL.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_AUDIO);
  
    if (Mix_OpenAudio(44100, MIX_DEFAULT_FORMAT, 2, 2048) < 0)
    {
        cout << "Error: " << Mix_GetError() << std::endl;
    }

    Mix_Music* song =  Mix_LoadMUS("sample.wav");
    Mix_PlayMusic(song, 1);

    Mix_FreeMusic(song);
    song = nullptr;

    Mix_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to play a simple song, that I converted to WAV. It is located within the program's folder. I didn't get any errors/warnings when compling and the libraries seem to be linked correctly. On failure, loadMUS returns NULL (which isn't the case) and PlayMusic returns -1 upon failure (which again isn't the case). Yet, when I run the program nothing is heard. This is my first time working with SDL.

Comment: `Mix_PlayMusic` is probably non-blocking, try adding `SDL_Delay`...

Comment: Do you actually intend to use SDL1 or SDL2?

Answer (score 0):

To just play a wave file this sample will work with SDL2:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_audio.h>


int main() {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_AUDIO);

    SDL_AudioSpec spec{};
    Uint8 *audio_buf{};
    Uint32 audio_len{};

    SDL_LoadWAV("path_to.wav", &spec, &audio_buf, &audio_len);

    SDL_AudioSpec ob_spec{};
    auto device = SDL_OpenAudioDevice(NULL, 0, &spec, &ob_spec, SDL_AUDIO_ALLOW_ANY_CHANGE);

    SDL_QueueAudio(device, audio_buf, audio_len);
    SDL_PauseAudioDevice(device, 0);

    SDL_Delay(5000);

    SDL_CloseAudioDevice(device);
    SDL_FreeWAV(audio_buf);

    SDL_QuitSubSystem(SDL_INIT_AUDIO);
}
```

BTW to link easy to SDL2 just use CMake with

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(sample_sdl VERSION 1.0)
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp)
set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 20)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE SDL2::SDL2 SDL2::SDL2main)
```